# Appropriate way to delete pointers within a vector

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers, vector

I have a multi threaded chat server and the main server class has a std::vector of clients. Each client is running on its own thread and they hold a pointer to the clients vector so they can communicate to each other.

Something that I'm unsure of is what is the best way of deleting an object from this vector when a client disconnects?

In this situation, is it okay to just lock the resource with a mutex and then allow it to remove/delete itself from the client vector?

Or would it be better for the server object that owns the clients vector to do some kind of check to see if that connection is closed and then for that class to manage the freeing of the resources?

I'm not interested in smart pointer solutions, this is a learning project.

Comment: A better question is why does the server need this vector?

Comment: _"I'm not interested in smart pointer solutions, this is a learning project."_ Huh? How does that make a difference? What if using smart pointers would come up as the correct solution?

Comment: The object should unregister itself in its destructor and call `delete this;` when it sees that the client disconnects. That's the cleanest solution IMO. I don't think that smart pointers are particularly useful here. You also need some synchronisation mechanism, of course -- that goes without saying. Other than, I'm afraid the question is a bit too broad for SO.

Comment: @ChristianHackl - Would you be able to elaborate a little on "synchronisation mechanism"?

Comment: @ChristianHackl nice ide, but wouldn't calling a `delete this` from within the class be a major design issue ?  Wouldn't this assumes that object is always allocated directly ?  I think this would cause undefined behaviour if the code would later evolve to use smart pointers, or for local objects.

Comment: @user1157885 could you show us the key elements of the server and the client class definition ?   Asked like that it's too broad.

Comment: @Christophe: `delete this` from within a class is no more a major design issue than any other `delete ptr;` anywhere. Bear in mind that such a client class will be designed and implemented from scratch to work in collaboration with other classes (such as the server class); it's not intended to be a general-purpose tool that can be "plugged" into any architecture.

Comment: @user1157885: Whenever two threads access the same data and at least one of them may write to it, then you must synchronise the access. Since C++11, this has become considerably easier with.

Comment: @ChristianHackl the class definition should then express this dependency, protecting the constructor and make it available to a server friend. That goes along with the delete this.

Comment: @Christophe: Well, it's something that needs to be documented, of course. A `friend` relationship may or may not be necessary; it all depends. The client class may be part of an internal library or module (and/or in some `internal` namespace). That's why I said the question was too broad.

Comment: @ChristianHackl - Thanks, that's all I needed to know. Everything you said is exactly the way I was thinking about it, I just needed to hear other peoples opinions on it to decide weather or not I should approach it in this way.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the arbitrary restriction of avoiding smart pointers makes it uninteresting (or even anti-interesting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the principle of **[separation of concerns](https://effectivesoftwaredesign.com/2012/02/05/separation-of-concerns/)**, from a design point of view, if the server launches the clients in the thread, I'd suggest to manage all this stuff in server class.

If connection is lost, the client thread could inform the server thread, and the server object can then do the necessary actions to remove the client from its watchlist and destory it.

The general idea would be something like:

```
class Server; 

class Client {
    Server* myserver;    // edit: sorry I forgot the backreference 
    clientid_t id;       // unique id, provided by the server at construction
public: 
    clientid_t get_id(); // for server when searching for a specific client
    ...                 // when connection is lost, tell the server
    ...                 // the destructor will do everything needed to clean up/close a chat
};

class Server {
    vector<Client*> chats;   // Or better, a smart pointer
    mutex critical;   // used when accessing to the chats container. 
public:  
    void listen_for_new_chats();  // create new chats and insert them in container
    void close_chat (clientid_t id);  // called when chat lost connection (abort)    
                                      // this function shall remove the chat from container and destroy client 
    ...  
};
```

This leaves you full control to let the server evolve independently of the client:

- if one day you choose to opt for queues or lists instead of vector, the client will not need to know.
- And the client won't need to know how the server manages the client (direct allocation, smart pointers, or directly as object in the container).

From the concurrency point of view, the this encapsulation will also make it more reliable.  The vector should be locked not only when removing a client, but also when accessing it for reading/searching.  By keeping the vector private to the server, you make sure that you'll never inadvertantly use the vector by forguetting a lock.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I like your proposed solution. I have two questions though.. 1. Lets say a client had a number of functions it could perform, for this basic example, would we typically have a single mutex within that client, and that single mutex would perform the locking for all the functions? So we're effectively locking the client itself rather than the functions?

Comment: Sorry, and for my second question... 2. What would be the best way for the server to "clean up" closed clients? I was thinking of removing the clients from the current vector and moving them to a "to be deleted" vector which a clean up thread would check every 5 minutes or so. Would that be a decent solution or is there a cleaner way of approaching that?

Comment: 1. the mutex shall protect your object as a whole. So in general you'd have a single mutex.  But it's dependent on your object structue:  if it has different independent parts, you could have sevaeral mutex, each protecting a part. But this is very tricky and could easily lead to deadlocks if not properly managed.  THe mutext shall certainly not be defined per function.  What you do in the function is locking/unlockng the mutex (for example by creating a local `lock_guard` using the single mutex)

Comment: 2. what would be the advantage to delay the clean up ?  I'd say close the client immediately (without lock on the server side) and remove it (there you need the lock).

Comment: I see. The main reason I was thinking of deleting it afterwards was because I wasn't sure how the server would know when a client was closed or not. My way of thinking was that when a client thread receives the "close connection" message it would need to somehow tell the server "Hey, i'm ready to be deleted".

Comment: Yes, "I'm ready to be deleted" wold be coded as `myserver->close_chat(id);`.  I think that the server then has no need to delay the removal and deletion of the client.

Comment: Yeah, but i'm just not really sure what the best way of notifying the server of that is. I'm quite new to threading, so I might be asking something really simple and obvious, but how would the child thread go about sending that message to the server? That's why I was thinking of having a "to be deleted" vector which the server would check regularly but I'm getting the feeling there's a much easier way to go about sending messages to the server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103426/discussion-between-christophe-and-user1157885).